# Send PHP errors through JSON

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am trying to debug a page that sends emails with attachments via ajax and when PHP kicks out an error, I get "Parse Error" because the error is not being sent back via JSON. Is there anyway to wrap up the PHP errors so I can alert them and see exactly what PHP errors are coming up?

What I am hoping to see in the js alert is the same thing you would see printed on the screen if this form was not submitted using ajax.

Comment: Open up Firebug / Chrome Inspector and check the Network tab.

Answer (score 5):

Use HTTP status codes. Simple and clean.

On the client side: You can handle the HTTP states with the success and failure callbacks of the common JavaScript frameworks.

On the server side: Use exceptions and handle them with a `catch` block. In the `catch` block set the HTTP status code and echo the exception message. Or use the less fancy [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) function and set the status code and error message in the callback function.

Comment: While this is a neat way to handle errors, it probably doesn't provide the granularity needed (if there are multiple possible errors...)

Comment: @zrvan: you can still pass the error information with the HTML body.

Comment: yes I think that this would help but I'd like to alert the exact same error php throws. Like "something blew up on line 41."

Answer (score 1):

Fatal errors usually can't be handled *.

Try improving your code and just don't make parse errors or other fatal errors. Handling warnings and notices is easy: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

*: It's possible but it takes a lot of effort.

Answer (score 1):

```
function json_error($msg) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 ' . $msg);
    die(json_encode(array('error' => $msg)));
}

json_error('something bad happened');
```

This will trigger the `error:` ajax callback on the JS side.

```
echo json_encode(array('anything' => 'really', 'any key' => 'any value'));
```

Will trigger the `success:` callback.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use exception-handling, look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php